# How to alias the git command in Git?

Tags: git, github

Alright, googling this for 10 minutes and the only examples I find are about aliasing things like `commit -m`, but how would I alias a command such as `git commit -m`? I tried using `git config --global alias.gco "git commit -m"` but this too only worked with the first command (`commit -m`). I also tried manually adding that command to the `gitconfig` file, but that didn't work either.

Is this impossible?

What i want to achieve:

I want to alias this: `git commit -m` So that instead of typing in `git commit -m`, I just type in `gco`

Comment: Have you tried `git config --global alias.gco 'commit -m'` ? I'm pretty sure I don't understand your question.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/master/gitalias.txt#L234

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, aliasing that command works, but aliasing the `git commit -m` command does not work. Sorry, there was a grammar mistake, must be where your confusion rooted from.

Comment: But then if the first works, why do you even need to try something else? Doesn't the one that works do what you want?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen so that I can type `gco [commit message]` instead of `git gco [commit message]` :)

Comment: @Taurus Here is your bible => https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases

Comment: @ckruczek what does this command do? it doesn't seem to have anything to do with aliases, do I run it anyways?

Comment: Try `git config --global alias.gco "commit -m"`

Comment: This needs elaboration. What you want to achieve? Aliasing git command (`git commit -m` > `git trololo`) or bash (`git commit -m` > `trololo`)?

Comment: This was just a an example you can instrument something like 'git commit -m'.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I want to alias this: `git commit -m`
So that instead of typing in `git commit -m`, I just type in `gco`

Comment: Ah, you want to execute `gco`, well this can't be solved by git alone. Create a shell script named `gco`.

Comment: updated the question guys, sorry if i was not clear enough.

Comment: Git alias can only be used to add or modify(?) commands invoked through git, you can't create new top-level commands that isn't invoked using git, in other words if your entire command line is supposed to be `gco message`, and not `git gco message`, then you need to create a shell script or batch file or similar named `gco` that invokes git. Git alias alone can't solve this.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs the latter, `git commit -m` > `trololo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per information you provided in the comments, it looks like you want bash alias, rather than git.

Following will allow you to make a commit via `gco` from the command line:

```
# Add me to your ~/.bashrc
alias gco='git commit -m'
```

But this is git alias, executed via `git gco`:

```
git config --global alias.gco "commit -m"
```

Comment: Please note, I wrote this answer as readable as possible. If you are nerd, please replace `bash` with `shell`, `.bashrc` with whatever is suitable for your shell, etc.